# What is the difference between mappedBy and CascadeType.ALL?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm learning Hibernate and faced a question: what is the difference between `mappedBy` and `CascadeType.ALL`?

We use `mappedBy` on the owning side in order to eliminate excessive persistence. For instance, with `mappedBy` we can replace

```
a.addB(b);
b.setA(a);
```

with

```
a.addB(b);
```

in a case of ONE-TO-MANY relationship between A and B, and MANY-TO-ONE between B and A (bidirectional).

Why do we need `CascadeType` in this case?

Comment: No, that's not, at all, what mappedBy is for. mappedBy is necessary to tell what the owner side of the bidirectional association is. And the owner side of a OneToMany/ManyToOne **must** be the Many side. And you **must** set the owner side, so `a.addB(b)` will **not** work (unless the method calls `b.setA(this)`.

Answer (score 2):

The `CascadeType` option tells hibernate which operations to also execute on B when executed on A.
If you for example persisted A without setting `CascadeType.Persist`, B would not be persisted.
The `mappedBy` option on the other hand creates a bidirectional relationship, with A being represented by a foreign key in the table of B.
If you actually need `CascadeType.ALL` depends on your use-case, it allows you to think of the relationship between A and B as a composition, with A owning B.